# Using a JavaScript file into Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem in my project and I set it using JavaScript, I want to know how can I use a JS file in an Ionic 3 project?

thanks.

Comment: the simplest method is to include it in the html page.. as you create a web page for browser...

Comment: thank you. But even when I do that in page Html, my funcitons are not recongnized, i got this error "change is not defined", change is the name of my function by the way.

Comment: add that code..

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153499/ionic-3

Answer (score 0):

I believe after adding your javascript to the html page you should be able to go into the ts file and make a declaration for all undefined properties.

e.g. `declare var change: any;`

Answer (score -1):

You can include your JS file in src/index.html and then use its methods/properties in TS file by declaring it as a variable by using declare keyword as Patrick Odum in the above answer told.